# Compile SASS +Grunt -Ruby -Python

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, libsass

is there any way to compile SASS without Ruby or Python?
I used **compass** and **grunt-sass/node-sass** but want to compile it on windows-machines without the need to install one of them.

Comment: sorry to say that ... if you want to use Grunt... nope 
But you can try to use for example PHPstorm oder Eclipse they have their own compiler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-sass doesn't require Python or Ruby to run. Python is only requiredto rebuild the binary if you're running on a Node version that doesn't have a precompiled binary available. EX: you're running the latest Node, but a really old node-sass.

Comment: that was correct. since i've updated my package.json it works fine with node-sass